# How put <Spanned> into list.setAdapter?

Tags: android, list, listview, arraylist, spanned

Simple but little tricky, if I have

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.double_row, R.id.doubleRow, articleItemsHelper));
```

it works if **articleItemsHelper** is **String**, but I wanna have HTML formatting in there so when **articleItemsHelper** is type **Spanned** this (adapter) doesn't work.

```
ArrayList<Spanned> articleItemsHelper = new ArrayList<Spanned>();
```

What's the solution?

EDIT: here is the solution - **custom adapter**

```
private static class SpannedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private LayoutInflater mInflater;
     private ArrayList<Spanned> mArticleList;

     public SpannedAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Spanned> articleList) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mArticleList = articleList;
     }

     public int getCount() {
         return mArticleList.size();
     }

     public Object getItem(int position) {
         return position;
     }

     public long getItemId(int position) {
         return position;
     }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ViewHolder holder;
         if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, null);
             holder = new ViewHolder();
             holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.singleRow);

             convertView.setTag(holder);
         } else {
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         }

         holder.text.setText(mArticleList.get(position));

         return convertView;
     }

     static class ViewHolder {
         TextView text;
     }
}
```

Then just regularly call

```
list.setAdapter(new SpannedAdapter(this, articleItemsHelper));
```

where

```
articleItemsHelper
```

is

```
ArrayList<Spanned>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how ArrayAdapter set the text of the rows:

```
    T item = getItem(position);
    if (item instanceof CharSequence) {
        text.setText((CharSequence)item);
    } else {
        text.setText(item.toString());
    }
```

As you can see, what it would do in your case is to call the `toString` method, and that's why it does not work. So, go ahead and write your own adapter, you have no choice in this case.

Comment: Oh, tnx. I posted the solution in upper post.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but I found an other way to do it, it can help people:

```
    simpleAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<Note>(this, R.layout.notelist, listeNotes ){
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
            {
                View v = super.getView(position, view, viewGroup);
                Note n = (Note) this.getItem(position);
                ((TextView)v).setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+n.getTitre() + "</b> <br/>"+n.getNote()));
                 return v;
            }
    };
```