# Android ListView - add HTML links when activity starts

Tags: java, android, html, listview

I have an activity that displays a listview of html links, each stored in a TextView, that the user can add and remove links from by specifying a name and web address. Each link is stored in the listview in HTML, as below, and the user would click the word 'google' to start the web browser.

`<a href='http://www.google.com'>google</a>`

I have tried several ways to make the links do this, including `android:autolink="web"` in the XML file, with the method below being the only way that works. However, I cannot call it as the activity is initializing (from onCreate() or onStart()) as the getChildAt method returns null.

```
 TextView wantedView = (TextView) listView.getChildAt(i);
 wantedView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
 wantedView.setClickable(true);
 wantedView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

However, if I set a clickable button that calls this code, then it works, although adding a new link to the list reverts the formatting.

Does anybody know why I can't access the TextView objects while initializing, and if there is another way to do this? I've posted my layout file and listview start up code below.

```
simplerow.xml <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:visibility="visible"
android:autoLink=""
android:gravity="center">

listview.xml <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test2);

    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    items = new String[]{ "<a href='http://www.facebook.com'>facebook</a>",
            "<a href='http://www.google.com'>google</a>",
            "<a href='http://www.twitter.com'>twitter</a>" };

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        list.add(items[i]);
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Test.this, R.layout.simplerow, list);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    makeLinksVisible();
}

private void makeLinksVisible() {
        int i = 0;
        TextView wantedView = (TextView) listView.getChildAt(i);

        while (wantedView != null) {
            String s = wantedView.getText().toString();
            wantedView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
            wantedView.setClickable(true);
            wantedView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

            i++;
            wantedView = (TextView) listView.getChildAt(i);
     }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the TextView stuff? It's not in the code you posted.

Comment: From a method called makeLinksVisible(). Originally I called this after setAdapter(adapter), but the textview returned null each time. When I added a button and called makeLinksVisible() from there, it worked. I've added it to the main comment.

Comment: See my answer below. The solution is to get the TextView from your ArrayAdapter, not your ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future viewers, here is a solution to the problem, and a brief description of how I found it.

I tried drschultz solution and noticed no change. He commented that using a textview with a string resource works. I tried this and realised the listview needed to be passed Spanned objects.

I found a solution for creating a Spanned Listview - [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4580664/how-put-spanned-into-listadapter/) - and then added an onItemClickListener, which called setMovementMethod on the Textview object provided.

I realised that the previous solution wasn't working because the adapter's 'getview' method wasn't providing a reference to the listview object, instead it was providing a copy with the same data (I think). Overriding the onItemClick method is a quick solution to get a reference to the list object, which allows you to manipulate it directly and do whatever you like to it.

I've added the code I used to test this solution below. It creates a list of two html references. The first click of a textview calls the onItemClick method, then any more clicks will take you to the web page specified.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    String s = new String("<a href=\"http://www.facebook.com\">facebook</a>");
    Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml(s);
    String s1 = new String("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a>");
    Spanned sp1 = Html.fromHtml(s1);

    listValues = new ArrayList<>();
    listValues.add(sp);
    listValues.add(sp1);
    setListAdapter(new SpannedAdapter(this, listValues));

    ListView l = getListView();
    l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            try {
                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view;
                TextView wantedView = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
                wantedView.setClickable(true);
                wantedView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let you create the class extending `ArrayAdapter<String>`, and then override the `getView(...)` method. There you will have to have a LayoutInflatter and a View that refer to a single row (simply named `row`). This is the best place to execute `row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {/*...*/}`. Do not forget to create a holder if you will have a lot of displayed at once data.

More about custom ArrayAdapters e.g. [here](https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to get the TextView from your ArrayAdapter, not your ListView. So if you are using a ListActivity, you would do something like:

```
ListView listView = getListView();
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) arrayAdapter.getView(0, null, null);
TextView wantedView = (TextView) frameLayout.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
wantedView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
wantedView.setClickable(true);
wantedView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This code of course assumes the use of a FrameLayout, but you would just replace that with whatever parent container holds your TextView that you are trying to access. Then in the `getView()` method, you would pass in the position of your TextView (I used zero just for an example). But if you try and use this code in your `onCreate()` it should work.

Comment: This isn't working unfortunately, the view does return the appropriate textview, but when the activity actually displays the link has not been created, it's still just displaying something like this as text <a href 'http://google.com'>google</a>

Comment: It's because you're not formatting your string correctly. You're using single quote marks instead of double. It should be like this: `<a href="http://google.com/">This is a link to google.com</a>`

Comment: That's the comment not formatting it, not sure why - in my code the text is exactly the same as yours

Comment: I just tried this in an Activity. I created a TextView and used a string resource for the text that looked like this: `<string name="clickable_link"><a href="http://google.com/">This is a link to google.com</a></string>`

Then in my `onCreate()` method I put this:
`TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clickableLink);`
`textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

Everything worked fine and when I clicked the link the browser launched and went to google.com.

Comment: Cheers for the help here, the reason that works is because the string resource is converted into a Spanned object. I've figured out a solution that I'm going to post to answer the main question, along with an explanation why it wasn't working previously.